# How to use click event on page load in knockout

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

```
<div class="free-sample" id="free-sample-component" data-bind="scope:'free_Sample_Component'">
    <button id="get-free-sample" data-bind="click:getFreeSample">Get Free Sample</button>
</div>
```

Above work in fine when click on free sample button but i want to use onload event. when page loaded then 'getFreeSample' should trigger.

Comment: did you tried data-bind="event: {change: getFreeSample()}"   ?

Comment: @Harishkuril I need to load free sample on page load so change event might be not work.

Comment: change event trigger on page load

Comment: @Harishkuril Can you give example please.

Comment: I am using change event in the form tag and its trigger on page load,
You can also try to add change event in the hidden field to trigger getFreeSample function on page load.

Comment: @Harishkuril Thanks.  data-bind="event: {change: getFreeSample()}" is working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use method call in if statement. But don't forget to make add return true in method.

```
<!-- ko if: isFreeShipping() -->
//My Code goes here
```

Comment: It will fire knockout template load.

Answer (score 0):

Replace button with span and try below way

```
<span class="testprice" data-bind="click: getTestCodeContent"><span data-bind="i18n: 'Add Test Code'"></span></span>
```

and on the JS file create a function like below.

```
getTestCodeContent: function () {
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: It will trigger on click. i want to replace on page load event but i don't have idea how to use on load event.